# Constant property value in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have schema where `a` property always equals 1. I have found a solution, but I don't like it:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    a: Number
});

schema.pre('save', function(){
    this.a = 1;
});
```

Can you please tell me if there is better way to do this? For example:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    a: 1
});
```

Comment: I recently wrote a plugin for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a default value, does it achieve what you want ?

`var schema = new Schema({
    a: {type: Number, default: 1}
});`

If you want to force it, the `pre` version is the best option.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that version too, but I want to force it. Anyway I think your answer is enough for me

Comment: I think there is one more hacky solution to force value )) `{type: Number, default: 1, enums: [1]}`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve this is to use a [virtual property](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-virtual). Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get persisted to MongoDB. Instead you can specify a getter function that get's called every time you access the `a` property:

```
schema.virtual('a').get(function () {
    return 1;
});
```

Now every document of `schema` will have a property `a` that equals `1`. Note however that because virtuals don't get persisted you are not able to query for them.

Answer (score 2):

Store constants as model properties.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    // ...
});
var myModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
myModel.a = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but for the future, you could use default value with a custom setter that always returns the old value, something like ...

```js
var schema = new Schema({
  a: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
    set(value) {
      return this.a;
    },
  }
});
```

The `default` option will initialize the field and the custom setter will ignore any new value and always reset the field to its previous value (that you set with default).