# How to do field validations in a mongoose schema based on other fields in the same schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Let's say we have :

```
const mealSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: { type: string, required: true },
  sauce: { type: string }
});
```

How can we make `sauce` mandatory if `title === "Pasta"` ?
The validation needs to work on update too.

I know that a workaround would be

1. Find
2. update manually
3. Then save

But the risk is that if I add a new attribute (let's say "price"), I forget to update it manually too in the workaround.

Comment: This may help.check the last answer..https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546639/11045279

Comment: Can you briefly how this answer could be applied to my case?

Answer (score 2):

### Document validators

Mongoose has several built-in validators.

- All SchemaTypes have the built-in required validator. The required validator uses the SchemaType's checkRequired() function to determine     if the value satisfies the required validator.
- Numbers have min and max validators.
- Strings have enum, match, minlength, and maxlength validators.

For your case you could do something like this

```
const mealSchema = Schema({
 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
title: { type: string, required: true }, 
sauce: { 
      type: string, 
      required: function() { 
        return this.title === "pasta"? true:false ; 
        }
  } 
});
```

If the built-in validators aren't enough, you can define custom validators to suit your needs.

Custom validation is declared by passing a validation function. You can find detailed instructions on how to do this in the [SchemaType#validate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

### Update Validators

`this` refers to the document being validated when using document validation. However, when running update validators, the document being updated may not be in the server's memory, so by default the value of `this` is not defined. So, What's the solution?

#### The context option lets you set the value of this in update validators to the underlying query.

In your case, we can do something like this:

```
const mealSchema = Schema({
 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
title: { type: string, required: true }, 
sauce: { type: string, required: true } 
});

mealSchema.path('sauce').validate(function(value) {
 // When running update validators with
 // the `context` option set to 'query', 
 // `this` refers to the query object. 

if (this.getUpdate().$set.title==="pasta") {
 return  true
}else{
 return false;
}
 }); 

const meal = db.model('Meal', mealSchema);

const update = { title:'pasta', sauce:false};

 // Note the context option 

const opts = { runValidators: true, context: 'query' }; 

meal.updateOne({}, update, opts, function(error) { assert.ok(error.errors['title']); });
```

Not sure if this answers your question. Hope this adds some value to your final solution.

Haven't tested it, pls suggest an edit if this solution needs an upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunalty, your solution works on save() but not on updates as "this" is undefined

Comment: @Gabriel, have addressed the update part too, hope this helps.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code but the validation isn't executed. Sauce is always required. I put console.log in validation function and nothing is ever printed :/

Comment: please check the documentation here...https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html....and when you find the correct solution, pls do edit the code in this answer. btw the code written in the answer is an exact template of the code mentioned in the documentation, I highly recommend you to check the docs, m positive that you would get your issue resolved there.